# updating in razor webmarix

Tags: razor, webmatrix

```
Line 22:    var sql3 = "UPDATE productori SET Name3=@0, detail2=@1, harga2=@2 WHERE id=@3";  
Line 23:    var db2 = Database.Open("SmallBakery");<br>
Line 24:      **db2.Execute(sql3 ,Name3, detail2, harga2);**
```

The bold area showing where the error is.

I have a problem with updating my database. I'm new with webmatrix and razor.

```
`Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = Name3 ]`
```

That is the error that I get. 
Below is my database format:

```
`ID = identity=big int  
Name nvarchar  
Description nvarchar  
price nvarchar`
```

Help me understand what I did wrong please.

Answer (score 0):

There is no column called Name3 in your database, but your SQL attempts to reference one with that name. Change the SQL so that the column names match what you have in the database. Also, you have 4 parameter markers in your SQL, but you only provide values for 3 of them so your SQL will never update any records.

Your SQL should look like this:

```
"UPDATE productori SET Name=@0, Description=@1, Price=@2 WHERE ID=@3";
```

Then you need to pass a value for the ID:

```
db2.Execute(sql3, Name3, detail2, harga2, variable_containing_id_value);
```

Comment: var sqlup =("UPDATE productori SET Name=@0, Description=@1, Price=@2 WHERE ID=@3");    
        var db2 = Database.Open("SmallBakery");    

        db2.Execute(sqlup, Name3, Description3, Price3, id);     

but when i run the code the value inside the database did not change

Comment: Then you need to check the value of id to make sure it matches a value in the database.

Comment: the id is passed since i can get the value inside the editing text box but during the ispost it like no sql were executed here the sample code 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RPen-j17VX3NH7ZO4XjZwRACDG5IDvZviixNbhs_oP8/edit

Comment: any comment and view is appreciated please